# No routes matched location "/ProductList/1" error in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to show the data I get from API on the screen. I need to send id to api and get data by id.  I want to take the category id in CategoryList.js and send it to ProductList.js, and in ProductList.js I want only the products in the software category, for example, to which category it belongs to, so I am trying to pull it from the api on the backend side according to the id. but react returns an error like this. what could be the reason for this. it's not actually an error, it's not underlined in red, there is a yellow warning sign, but nothing appears on the screen. By the way when I try postman to get data from api it works.

**ERROR**
router.ts:11 No routes matched location "/ProductList/1"

**My categoryList.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { Link, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { CategoryContext } from "../Contexts/CategoryContext";



export default function CategoryList() {

   

    const { Categories } = useContext(CategoryContext)
    

    const truncateOverview = (string, maxLength) => {
        if (!string) return null;
        if (string.length <= maxLength) return string;
        return `${string.substring(0, maxLength)} ...`;
    }


    return (


        <div className="row">

            {Categories.map((category, i) => (

                <div className="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch" key={i}>
                    <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                       
                        <Link to={`/ProductList/${category.categoryId}`}>
                            <img src={category.categoryImage} className="card-img-top" alt="" />
                        </Link>
                        
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">{category.cotegoryName}</h5>
                            <p className="card-text">{truncateOverview(category.cotegoryDescription, 50)}</p>
                            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">

                                <h2><span className="badge badge-info">{category.categoryStatus}</span></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            ))}

        </div>


    )
}
```

**ProductList.js**

```
import {useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect,} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function ProductList() {

   // const { products } = useContext(ProductByIdContext);

    let id = useParams()

    console.log("id-->",id)

    const [products, SetProducts] = useState({});

    const url = `http://localhost:64082/api/products/getproductbycategoryid/${id}`
  
    const fetchData = () => {
      axios.get(url)
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
              SetProducts(response.data)
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
          })
  }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
    },[])
  
    return (
        <>


             <table className='table table-striped table-hover'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th>product is offerable</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Product Description</th>
                        <th>Product is sold</th>
                        <th>Category Name</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
             
                        {products.map((product) =>(
                           
                            <tr>
                                <td>{product.productId}</td>
                                <td>{String(product.isOfferable)}</td>
                                <td>{product.productName}</td>
                                <td>{product.productDescription}</td>
                                <td>{String(product.isSold)}</td>
                                <td>{product.categoryName}</td>
                                
                            </tr>
                          
                        
                        ))}
                   


                </tbody>
            </table> 

      


        </>
    )


}
```

**My App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginPage from './Components/LoginPage'
import SignUpPage from './Components/SignUpPage'
import Home from './Components/Home';
import ProductList from './Components/ProductList'
import CategoryList from './Components/CategoryList'

function App() {

  return (

   
      <div id='nav'>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <NavLink to="/" >Home  </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/LoginPage" >Login </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/SignUpPage" >Sign Up  </NavLink> {/* burası hep sabit gözükür*/}
              
          </ul>
        </nav>


        <div>
        
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/LoginPage" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/SignUpPage" element={<SignUpPage />} />
            <Route path="/ProductList" element={<ProductList />} />
            <Route path="/CategoryList" element={<CategoryList />} />
          </Routes>
          
        </div>
      </div>
     
  );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where are your routes?

Comment: my routes are in the App.js.

Comment: /ProductList route should be dynamic because you are sending the id parameter in link. Something like that <Route path="/ProductList /:id">

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

I added the following route element to where my routes are and the problem is solved

```
<Route path="/ProductList/:id" element={<ProductList />} />
```